# Need to avoid undefined reference to `WinMain' in a static library that needs to use a linker script *.ld file

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

I have 3 static libraries, one of them (BinaryMain) has the entry function

> ```
> int32_t  main(int32_t arg, char** argv) {
> ..
> ..
> }
> ```

I want to create an executable by combining these three static libraries (BinaryMain, Binary1, Binary2)

While creating static binary (Binary1 and Binary 2) i want to use specific linker script file (binary1.ld, binary2.ld) and also generate map files for each of them.
BinaryMain had reference to variables/functions in Binary1 and Binary2 which i suppressed using

> **attribute**((weak))

.

But while creating static library (Binary1 and Binary2) i get the error

> (.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `WinMain'

the command line for each static binay used is

> g++ -o libbinary1.a -Wl,--start-group component1.a component2.a
>   -static -Xlinker -Map=binary1.map -Tbinary1.ld -Wl,--end-group -LTools\win-builds-64\lib          -LTools\msys_Python\Python34 -lstdc++ -lgcov -lpython34

i know main entry is only in libBinaryMain.a and is not contained in libbinary1.a or libbinary2.a but how do i tell the linker to stop looking for 'WinMain' when linking these two binaries.

I have an equivalent target build, where all the three binaries are elf, one containing the main. I am not sure wether my attempt to create a pc build would work with an exe.

Awaiting some valuable suggestion.
Thanks in Advance
Sid

Comment: What do you understand by static binary?

Comment: by mentioning static binary, i understand the final exe would contain all the   referenced code copied, instead of just being referenced inside the exe. So the size of the exe would be large if it is static binary. If i am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The linker thinks you're building a GUI application rather than a console application, so it's looking to resolve the entry point `WinMain` instead of `main`.  You can use `-mconsole` to tell the linker you want a console application.

Comment: i have added the -mconsole option, but still the same error: undefined reference to 'WinMain' occur